# Simple question about limits of integration with derivative under integral sign.

Tags: integration, real-numbers

Just for clarification purposes i will make a U-substitution that makes no sense. I am aware this integral has no exact solution over the following domain.

$$ I'(b) = \int_0^{2 } \frac{sin(x)}{e^{bx}} $$

if for some reason i wanted to let

$$ x = \sqrt {(b^2+k^2) } $$

so that

$$ dx = \frac{k}{\sqrt{b^2+k^2}} dk $$

which limits of integration would i have for the above integral?
I am quite confused about how to treat the "b" when it comes to the limits of integration.

Thank you kindly for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

In general, all you need to do is find the values of $k$ which correspond to the $x$ limits of $0$ and $2$.

However, your example has $x = \sqrt {(b^2+k^2)}$ and, for $b^2>0$, there is **no** value of $k$ which corresponds to $x=0$.

Suppose instead you had said $x=b+k$, then the $k$ limits would be $-b$ and $2-b$.

Comment: so then this would be a substitution that i would not be able to do correct?

Comment: That's right - it is not possible with these $x$ limits.